Elevated Button OnPressed function not working
please when create an elevated button and then give it an empty funtion it indicates an error which doesn't allow my code to run. Even if i give it a simple function it still doesnt work. can someone please help me
i was expecting it to work. I even copied some solutions directly from here but still not working.a screenshot of the error

Try replace {}() to null to run your application.

It seems that the error is not directly related to the onPressed. I'd recommend adding the code as a code snippet instead of a screenshot, and the error message as well.

I am pretty sure you might having const on top level

Remove const keyword from hierarchy a function is not a const. that's why it's giving error.
